# IBM Watson Natural Language Classifier

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson

one simple question: how can I create more than one classifier within a instance of Natural Language Classifier using the beta toolkit?

I've asked that because I don't know how to upload and train a new classifier after I've just deployed one.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about the Toolkit. You can manage your training data and classifiers by using the IBM Watson™ Natural Language Classifier Toolkit web application. The toolkit gives you a **unified** view of *all the classifiers that are running in the same Bluemix service instance*. So you need to create another classifier and use the toolkit to manage.

I think you can view this document, about Natural Language Classifier using [Toolkit](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-classifier/tool-overview.html#managing-toolkit).

Obs.: The first classifier is free, but each other you will need to pay.

See the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/#create_classifier) to use NLC.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sayuri mentions above, use the [Toolkit](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-classifier/tool-overview.html#managing-toolkit) to manage your Classifiers.

Something to keep in mind that when you create the first NLC instance (the little box in Bluemix), this is called a service instance.  Within this service instance, you can have up to 7 unique classifiers.  If you need to create an 8th classifier, you will need to create a new service instance.

Comment: Hi Daniel! I can't find in the documentation the part in which it talks about 7 unique classifier. Can you give me the link where I can find this information? Thanks in advanced

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing this in the documentation.  But you can see it for yourself if you just create an instance of NLC, and go create 8 classifiers by hand.  The first 7 will return an OK status, and you will get an error status on the 8th one.